# Assigning two arrays equal to each other problems

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, memory-management, reference

```
public static void main(String[]args) {


    int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] y ;
    y = x;
    x[1] = 11;
    x = new int[2];

    x[0]=99;
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
      System.out.print(y[i] + " ");
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
          System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
}
```

answer is

```
1 11 3 4 
99 0
```

My question is I thought when you assign two arrays, they share the same changes since they are objects... like when I set `x[1] = 11;` it changed the value of `y`, so shouldn't y still be identical to x after changing it to a 2-sized array, or since I am changing the size they no longer point to the same address?

Comment: Your code creates 2 arrays, one of length 4, and one of length 2. For reference, let's call them A4 and A2. So, `x = A4, y = A4`, then `x[1] = 11` means you just changed A4. `x = A2` then `x[0] = 99` means you just changed A2.

Comment: the line of   x = new int[2]; ensured a new array is created and assigned to reference x. while y is still referring to the previous array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

`{1, 2, 3, 4}` is allocated as an array. A reference to it is assigned to `x`.

```
int[] y ;
y = x;
```

A reference to that same array is assigned to `y` as well.

```
x[1] = 11;
```

The array that both `x` and `y` refer to is now `{1, 11, 3, 4}`.

```
x = new int[2];
```

A new array is allocated, due to Java semantics, as `{0, 0}`. A reference to it is assigned to `x`. Now `x` and `y` refer to two different arrays. There is no resizing being done.

```
x[0]=99;
```

The array referred to by `x` is changed, and now contains `{99, 0}`. This has nothing to do with the array `y` refers to, which is still happily `{1, 11, 3, 4}`.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = new int[2];
```

This line creates a *new* array with a length of 2, and then makes `x` point to that new array. At this point, the original array is only referenced by `y`.

```
x[0] = 99;
```

This line assigns the 0th element in that *new* array to 99, and therefore the original array is left unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Let me take you through your code line by line

When you do

Stage #1:

`int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};`

an array object is created inside the **HEAP** and assigns the address of this **INTEGER ARRAY OBJECT** to the reference variable `x`

Stage #2:

```
int[] y ;
y = x;
```

another reference variable `y`,that can store integer array object is created and is now storing the same **address** as the previous variable `x`

Stage #3:

```
x = new int[2];
```

with the use of the keyword `new` we are instructing the JVM to create a *new* **integer array object** inside the **heap** of length 2, and send the address of this newly created object to store inside `x`.

This means the data (address of the previous object) is now reassigned with the new data (address of the newly created object).

But this doesn't mean that the address inside the reference variable `y` is also getting reassigned as well.

Which means it is still holding the data (address of the previous object) inside it, and when you use the for loop to print both the arrays you get the output as:

`1 11 3 4`

`99 0`

Comment: For a 404 Brain Not Found that is a very nice answer ;-) +1!

Comment: Still didn't get those juicy +25 points along with the green tick mark beside my answer :'(

Comment: yeah. FeelsBadMan, wish we could up vote our own stuff too ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have commented your code in-line with what is happening with your variables and memory allocation/memory references, let me know if it is clear.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {


    int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // x -> [1|2|3|4]
    //the reference x points to this data structure in memory
    int[] y ; // y (variable y is not yet pointing to anywhere in memory)
    y = x; // y, x  -> [1|2|3|4] x and y points to the same array
    x[1] = 11; //y,x -> [1|11|3|4] 
    x = new int[2]; //y -> [1|11|3|4] and x -> [0|0]

    x[0]=99; // y -> [1|11|3|4] and x -> [99|0]
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
      System.out.print(y[i] + " ");
    System.out.print("");
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
          System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about this piece of code..

```
y = x;  // this actually only reference of same array is going to assign.
```

In above code only ref. is going to assigned, both `x` and `y` is referring to same array object.

So, if any changes done in `x` will be reflected to `y` automatically.

From here on

```
 x = new int[2];
```

`x` is assigned with new array of size two. So, A totally new array of size 2 is created and assigned to it.

so Now on, if any changes in `x` would not reflect to `y` and vice-versa.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

After you use the keyword new, a new array object with a different address is created.
At line 4:  x = new int[2];

So you are assigning a new array object to x. This is no longer the same array that you initialized in line 1.  Hence the change in values.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] y ;
y = x;
```

Till Line no 3 both x and y have same value of array as initialized

The format of using new in Java is
name = new type [size];

```
x = new int[2];
```

This will allocate memory to x as specified (2 integer values in array). This will overwrite the value which x held earlier

Further the default values when array is initialized are 
0 for numeric type
false for boolean type
NULL for reference type

Thus the array had value {0,0} which was then changed to {99,0}.